# Is it possible to tell if the Text change on an entry was from code or from the UI?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-entry

I am working on a `Xamarin` project and I need to be able to tell if the changes that occur to the text in an `Entry` view are from the code or from the UI, is this possible in `Xamarin`? or is there a known work around to do this.

I know about the `OnTextChanged` event but this only tells you that the `Text` property has changed, and gives you access to the old and new value of the `Text` property. It does not differentiate between different causes of text change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some idea from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288466/how-to-distinguish-in-a-c-sharp-event-if-a-change-was-made-from-code-or-by-the-u), check if the entry is focused to differentiate between different causes of text change:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myEntry.TextChanged += MyEntry_TextChanged;
}

private void MyEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = sender as Entry;
    if (entry.IsFocused)
    {
        //change from UI
        Console.WriteLine("change from UI");
    }
    else{
        //change from code
        Console.WriteLine("change from code");
    }
}
```

**Update**: The **better** way to solve op's problem:

You can set a flag yourself that tells your code to ignore the event. For example:

```
private bool ignoreTextChanged;

private void textNazwa_TextCanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ignoreTextChanged) return;
}
```

Create a method and use this to set the text instead of just calling Text = "...";::

```
private void SetTextBoxText(TextBox box, string text)
{
    ignoreTextChanged = true;

    box.Text = text;

    ignoreTextChanged = false;
}
```

Refer: [ignoreTextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8288504/10539446)

Comment: I am currently doing something like this, but I ran into a roadblock when using this for my use case. However I found the accepted answer in the thread to be quite useful. So thank you for that. Considering that I don't know if I should mark this answer as correct or not  :)

Comment: @Kikanye I updated my answer so that the solution you use is also there.  You can accept it now and we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

you can use EntryRenderer to detect keypress event and use that flag to detect  the change by code or by UI.

Here are the step:
 -  Exetend your entry control with new event OnTextChangeByUI
 -  Write custom render for both platform

e.g for android it will be something like this

```
public class ExtendedEntryRender : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.KeyPress += ((Entry)Element).OnTextChangeByUI;


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting making a custom Editor control? Can you elaborate on this answer